# Problem listing Google Container Registry images via Docker Registry HTTP API V2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

We have some problem trying to list Google Container Registry images via [Docker Registry HTTP API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)

When executing this command:

```
curl -k -s -X GET "https://eu.gcr.io/v2/_catalog" -L -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}'
```

Sometimes we get an empty json `{"repositories":[]}` and sometimes we get the correct json with all the information `{"repositories":["projectname/image1","projectname/image1"]}`

Does Google Container Registry fully support Docker Registry HTTP API V2?
Is anybody else experiencing this issue?

Comment: There's an error in your command that -H value has single quotes (') instead of double (") so the ${TOKEN} value will not be evaluated.

Comment: Also note that the response you'll be getting may contain a `next` field with the URL you should query to fully enumerate the responses. But the fact that this endpoint _sometimes_ works is pointing to the fact that there's a bug in GCR.

Comment: Please send your your project IDs you'd expect in the catalog response to `gcr-contact@google.com` for debugging, and link to this question in your email.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google mail sent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user is hitting a bug in a proprietary product that's being resolved by the product team. User has been put in touch with the support email.